# RequireJS managing large modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Only now I have considered using RequireJS and AMD modules.
So far - all the things have been managed through few global variables and self invoking functions.

Example, for how my module would looke like:

```
function HugeModule() {
    //usage = new HugeModule();  
};
HugeModule.prototype.functionX = function() {
    //Lets say - around 50 functions for HugeModule prototype
};

HugeModule.SubModule = function() {
    //usage = new HugeModule.SubModule();
    //And here could be multiple subModules like this
};
HugeModule.SubModule.prototype.functionX = function() {
    //Lets say - around 20 functions for HugeModule.SubModule prototype
};
```

Now I would have written it like this, I would have split it between at least 4 files:

```
//HugeModule.js
var HugeModule = (function() {
    function HugeModule() {
        //usage = new HugeModule();  
    };
    return HugeModule;
})();
//HugeModule.somePrototypeFunctions.js
(function() {
    HugeModule.prototype.functionX = function() {
        //Lets say - around 50 functions for HugeModule prototype
    };
})();
//HugeModule.SubModule.js
(function() {
    HugeModule.SubModule = function() {
        //usage = new HugeModule.SubModule();
        //And here could be multiple subModules like this
    };
})();
//HugeModule.SubModule.someOtherPrototypeFunctions.js
(function() {    
    HugeModule.SubModule.prototype.functionX = function() {
        //Lets say - around 20 functions for HugeModule.SubModule prototype
    };
})();
```

I would really like to write these modules with AMD modules and RequireJS, I have a basic idea how they should be written, but I am not sure - how would I split them between multiple modules.

I could write it like this:

```
define([], function() {
    function HugeModule() {
        //usage = new HugeModule();  
    };
    HugeModule.prototype.functionX = function() {
        //Lets say - around 50 functions for HugeModule prototype
    };
    return HugeModule;
});
```

but I would like to split it between multiple files. I would prefer not to use build tools that concatenates files.

What I would like is one requirable module - `HugeModule` and it would resolve all the dependencies for `HugeModule.somePrototypeFunctions`, and `HugeModule.SubModule` (and this would resolve dependencie for `HugeModule.SubModule.someOtherPrototypeFunctions`)

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an important caveat: what you are trying to do does not lend itself well to how ES6 classes work. If you are ever to write ES6 classes or write in a language that has a class syntax similar to ES6 (TypeScript, for instance, has classes that are ES6 + type annotations), you'll run into having to work around the class syntax or run into transpilation problems. Think about refactoring your `HugeModule` into multiple smaller classes to avoid these problems.  (See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563) for a discussion of the problem in the context of TypeScript.)

If the caveat above is not a concern, you can achieve your goal by organizing your code like the following. I've used this pattern for many years successfully.

`HugeModule.js` just combines the parts of the class and provide a facade for the rest of the code:

```
define(["./HugeModuleCore", "./HugeModuleA", "./HugeModuleB"], function (HugeModuleCore) {
    return HugeModuleCore;
});
```

`HugeModuleCore.js` creates the class and creates some "core" methods on it:

```
define([], function () {
    function HugeModule() {
    };

    HugeModule.prototype.someCoreFunction = function() {
    };

    return HugeModule;
});
```

`HugeModuleA.js` adds some category of methods to the core:

```
define(["./HugeModuleCore"], function (HugeModule) {
    HugeModule.prototype.someFunction = function() {
    };

    // You don't really need to return anything here.
});
```

`HugeModuleB.js` adds some other category of methods to the core:

```
define(["./HugeModuleCore"], function (HugeModule) {
    HugeModule.prototype.someOtherFunction = function() {
    };

    // You don't really need to return anything here.
});
```